# Sharepoint 2013 Add Enterprise Keywords Error

Tags: 2013, document-library, enterprise-keywords

I have a Documents Library with some documents in my test environment. When I add a document I would like to add also some enterprise keywords like I do in the live environment. When I add the doc and only one enterprise keyword, I get no errors. When I try to add the doc with 2 or more enterprise keywords I get the error:

[image]

I tried with google:

- create a new library
- add enterprise keywords to different items
- add enterprise keywords to different items in another library
- restart iis
- I have also space in my SQL to the Log-Files: at the moment 10 GB free of 50 GB.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Nobody? .-. T.T